# Nginx + fastcgi to run PHP script , but it kept telling me "File not found"

Tags: php, nginx, cgi

Here's part of config in the server block:

I was unable to execute any php script , I placed a file named `test.php` under /var/html , but when I point to `http://localhost/test.php` , I got a result:

`File not found.`,

That's not generated by nginx , since it's different from the 404 page of nginx.

```
location / {
    root   /var/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php; 
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi.conf;
    }
```

Did I miss anything ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're defining the document root under the `/` location, and this doesn't apply to the `\.php$` location. Move the `root` directive outside the `/` location so that it is applied to both.

```
root   /var/html;
location / {
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

Comment: [Root inside locations](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Root_inside_Location_Block) is bad, by the way. (Relevant to question, not the answer).

Comment: @DmitryVerkhoturov and mgorven Thanks to both of you defining one root in nginx conf resolved my error. I was searching it for 2 days ..... THANKS